# MySQL dynamic Pivot to C# GridView with dates and sum

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, dynamic, pivot

I have the following data taken from a MySQL database:

```
+------------+------------+----------------+
| competency | totalscore | date_evaluated |
+------------+------------+----------------+
|     A      |      0     |     null       |
|     B      |      0     |     null       |
|     C      |      0     |     null       |
|     D      |      0     |     null       |
|     E      |      5     |   2018-03-01   |
|     F      |      4     |   2018-03-01   |
|     E      |      4     |   2018-03-02   |
|     F      |      3     |   2018-03-02   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Which is retrieved from two separate tables

```
+-----------------+
|  competencies   | 
+-----------------+
|  competency_ID  |
|  competency     |
+-----------------+

+-----------------+
|  scoring_self   | 
+-----------------+
|  student_ID     |
|  competency_ID  |
|  score          |
|  date_evaluated |
+-----------------+
```

I would like to display on an .aspx page in the following form:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Date Evaluated |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F    |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 2018-03-01     |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   5   |   4    |
| 2018-03-02     |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   4   |   3    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where the score is 0 and the evaluation date is null if the user has not attempted it yet. I've tried to create a dynamic pivot table as the number of competencies can change depending on the subject using the following prepared statements.

```
SET @mysql = NULL;

SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('(CASE WHEN score IS NOT NULL THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS `',
competency, '`')) INTO @mysql
FROM (SELECT competency, scoring_self.score FROM competency LEFT JOIN
scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID
ORDER BY competency) AS sub;


SET @mysql2= CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(ss.date_evaluated)) AS `Date
Evaluated`, ' , @mysql, 
'FROM competency c INNER JOIN scoring_self ss
ON c.competency_ID = ss.competency_ID
GROUP BY ss.date_evaluated;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @mysql2;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However, I've only managed to get it in the following form:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Date Evaluated |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F    |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 2018-03-01     |   5   |   5   |   5   |   5   |   5   |   5    |
| 2018-03-02     |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It appears to be only pulling the first set of scores from the first date and I am not too sure what's going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Also, I'm not too sure where to put a WHERE clause in the prepared statement to only retrieve the scores of a single student.

**EDIT**: I've tried the changes as suggested by jQuery with a few tweak of my own:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                     CONCAT('(CASE WHEN score IS NOT NULL THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS `', competency, '`')) INTO @mysql
FROM 
    (SELECT competency 
     FROM competency 
     LEFT JOIN scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID 
                            AND scoring_self.student_ID = <redacted>
     GROUP BY DATE(scoring_self.date_evaluated), competency) AS sub;
```

This returns an output of:

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| Date Evaluated |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F    |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| 2018-03-01     |   5   |   5   |   5   |   5   |   5   |   5    |
| 2018-03-01     |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4    |
| 2018-03-02     |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4   |   4    |
| 2018-03-02     |   3   |   3   |   3   |   3   |   3   |   3    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It appears the scores are not mapping to the columns they are supposed to for reasons that are beyond me.

EDIT 2:

**SOLVED** Courtesy of jQuery

Final prepared statement should look like this

```
SET @mysql_dynamic = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
                 'MAX(CASE WHEN competency = ''',
      competency,
      ''' AND competency IS NOT NULL THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS `',
      competency,
      '`'
            )
        )
    FROM (SELECT competency, scoring_self.score, student_ID FROM competency LEFT JOIN
scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID 
ORDER BY competency) AS sub
);

SET @mysql = CONCAT('SELECT ss.date_evaluated, ', @mysql_dynamic, ' 
FROM (SELECT date_evaluated, competency, scoring_self.score, scoring_self.student_ID FROM competency LEFT JOIN
scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID 
ORDER BY competency) AS ss WHERE ss.date_evaluated IS NOT NULL AND ss.student_ID = \'',<redacted>,'\' GROUP BY date_evaluated DESC');

PREPARE stmt FROM @mysql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The above provides the desired outcome that is filterable by student ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're close with the code below

THIS WILL GIVE YOU THE DESIRED RESULT:

```sql
SET @sql_dynamic = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
                 'max(case when competency = ''',
      competency,
      ''' and competency is not null then score end) AS `',
      competency,
      '`'
            )
        )
    FROM (SELECT competency, scoring_self.score FROM competency LEFT JOIN
scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID
ORDER BY competency) AS sub
);

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ss.date_evaluated,', 
              @sql_dynamic, ' 
           FROM (SELECT date_evaluated, competency, scoring_self.score FROM competency LEFT JOIN
scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID
ORDER BY competency) AS ss WHERE ss.date_evaluated is not null
           GROUP BY date_evaluated DESC'
       );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

On that code, the score is now properly mapped to competency.

UPDATE:

Found the culprit, it is because of the `WHEN score IS NOT NULL THEN score ELSE 0` , try removing the `IS NOT NULL` and `ELSE 0` on your first code, that should map the column properly with your code. But try to see my update first and test run.

UPDATE:

This is from your code which I tweaked a litte:

```sql
SET @mysql = NULL;

SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
                 'max(case when competency = ''',
      competency,
      ''' and competency is not null then score else 0 end) AS `',
      competency,
      '`'
            )
) INTO @mysql
FROM (SELECT competency, scoring_self.score FROM competency LEFT JOIN
scoring_self ON competency.competency_ID = scoring_self.competency_ID
ORDER BY competency) AS sub;


SET @mysql2= CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(ss.date_evaluated)) AS `Date
Evaluated`, ' , @mysql, 
'FROM competency c INNER JOIN scoring_self ss
ON c.competency_ID = ss.competency_ID
GROUP BY ss.date_evaluated;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @mysql2;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Hi, please set the whole query to session variable not just the columns,

Comment: I've tried your new edit but it gives me what I originally started with. The scores don't seem to be mapping to the columns properly.

Comment: @Winz kindly try again my new update and see, I think it only needs a little of tweaking to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! You're a lifesaver! Any idea how I can further refine it by student ID?

Comment: Glad it work :). what do you mean by "further refine it by student ID", please elaborate and I'll see if I can help

Comment: you can post another question regarding that with more details, i'll see if I can help you again :)

Comment: In the scoring_self table there is a student ID field that dictates which student the score refers to. I'm not sure how to restrict to only show the data for a specific student based on their ID number.

Comment: you can use `WHERE` clause to referenced the student.

Comment: I just fixed it, will add it to the update. Thank you so much for your help once again!